# Tabular incremental update

Tags: database, auto-update, tabular

Let me first say that I don't have any solid SQL knowledge and it is the first time I'm working with Tabular, so, please, pardon me for any inaccuracy or naive mistake.

I have a big dataset on Tabular linked to a server which receives entries everyday. Whenever I process (update) the main table to which all the tables are linked I'm basically reprocessing a lot of entries that I already have plus a few new ones.

I'd like to figure out a way to process only entries that I don't have yet and not the entire dataset.